# Using functions.php or something instead of content-single-product.php and content-product.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Currently I am using content-single-product.php and content-product.php to override each product because I use ACF to check if something is true or not.

They say I should use functions.php instead or something because it is bad to override in the templates. How could I change my current code to be used in functions.php instead?

content-single-prduct.php:

```
// Hide price if checked
$showPriceNo = get_field('show_price');
if ($showPriceNo) {
    echo "JAAAA";
    //remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
    //add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'businessbloomer_remove_prices', 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'remove_price', 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'remove_price', 10, 2 );
}

//Remove buying button
$showBuyButtonNo = get_field('show_buy_button');
if ($showBuyButtonNo) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
}

//Remove related products
$showRelatedProductsNo = get_field('show_related_products');
if ($showRelatedProductsNo) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
}
```

content-product.php:

```
// Hide price if checked
    $showPriceNo = get_field('show_price');
    if ($showPriceNo) {
        echo "JAAAA";
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'remove_price', 10, 2 );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'remove_price', 10, 2 );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'remove_price', 10, 2 );
    }

    //Remove buying button
    $showBuyButtonNo = get_field('show_buy_button');
    if ($showBuyButtonNo) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You just need to add your all code in functions.php file

Comment: @dipmala did not work. Dont really know what you mean other than copy paste this to functions.php, but that does not work

Comment: But what thing stop after you put this in functions.php file?

Comment: It does not know which product to check ACF on

Comment: ok got your point now check my answer it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check below code it will work for you.

```
       add_filter('wp_head', 'function_to_be_removed');
        function function_to_be_removed()
        {
             global $post;
              $postid= $post->ID;
            // Hide price if checked
        $showPriceNo = get_field('show_price',$postid);
        if ($showPriceNo) {
            echo "JAAAA";
            //remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
            //add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'businessbloomer_remove_prices', 10, 2 );
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'remove_price', 10, 2 );
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'remove_price', 10, 2 );
        }

        //Remove buying button
        $showBuyButtonNo = get_field('show_buy_button',$postid);
        if ($showBuyButtonNo) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        }

        //Remove related products
        $showRelatedProductsNo = get_field('show_related_products',$postid);
        if ($showRelatedProductsNo) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
        }

        // Hide price if checked
            $showPriceNo = get_field('show_price',$postid);
            if ($showPriceNo) {
                echo "JAAAA";
                add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'remove_price', 10, 2 );
                add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'remove_price', 10, 2 );
                add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'remove_price', 10, 2 );
            }

            //Remove buying button
            $showBuyButtonNo = get_field('show_buy_button',$postid);
            if ($showBuyButtonNo) {
                remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Changed add_filtera to add filter. It did nothing, and didnt give me any errors either :/

Comment: now check i have change init action with wp_head it will work

Comment: Worked some ways, but some differences was there to the result I had. But it works, thanks